# Object literal and static variable

Tags: javascript

Object literal is considered as a static object.

So, object literal should contain only static variable, but in the following piece of code

```
var obj = {
    a : "hello",
    foo : function(){
        console.log(this.a);
        console.log(obj.a);
    }
};
```

I can access `a`, in a static way `obj.a` and in a non-static way `this.a`.

Is `a` a static variable?

Comment: "Object literal are considered as static object". Really?

Comment: A static variable can be referenced both via `Type.var` and `this.var` in most langauges.  Being able to reference using `this.var` doesn't make it non-static.

Comment: @bfavaretto it behave like singletons no? and you can't do var b = new obj();

Comment: There are no static variables in JavaScript.

Comment: get rid of all what you know from java or whatever language you come from and learn javascript - it's misunderstood very often but if you take the time to learn about it's prototypal nature you will be surprised how powerful it is although it has several "shortcomings" in terms of classical thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing a bunch of different things.

You've created an object named `obj` that has a field named `a`.  That field can be accessed as `obj.a` (or `obj['a']` if you prefer).  If you arrange for some other variable to refer to `obj`, then it's also available via that variable.

One way to arrange for some other variable to point to `obj` is to take a field of `obj` which is defined as a function/closure, and invoke it using "method" syntax, as in `obj.foo()`.  That means that inside the body of `foo`, for the duration of that invocation, the special variable `this` will refer to `obj`.  Therefore code within that function can access `obj.a` via `this.a`.

None of this has anything to do with static vs dynamic scope, or singletons, or "class" vs "instance" members, or any of that.  It's just an object.

Comment: even more important - you could do something like `var func = obj.foo` and break the `this` reference!

Answer (score 3):

The object literal is **not a static class**, it's an instance of `Object`; therefore `obj.a` can't be static either. Perhaps the confusion lies in the fact that the `{}` notation actually creates an object:

```
typeof {
    a : "hello",
    foo : function(){
        console.log(this.a);
        console.log(obj.a);
    }
};

"object"
```

It's equivalent to:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.a = 'hello';
obj.foo = function() {}
```

**Conclusion**

Static properties only have a meaning in class-oriented languages, but the same concept of classes in JavaScript is arguably non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

`obj.a` is "static", the way you refer to it. You would only use `this` in this way when using `new obj()` - so `obj` would have to be a function.

By default `this` refers to the parent object when used inside a function that is an object member. In the case of your code `obj` is the parent object.

An example of using prototypes and `this`:

```
var Obj = function(){this.a = "hi"};
Obj.prototype.foo = function(){
    console.log(this.a);
}
Obj.b = "sth";
var myObj = new Obj();
myObj.foo(); // "hi"
console.log(myObj.b); // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not so simple , check the

```
 let baba = {
    a: 12,
    foo: function () {
        baba.a = 13;
        this.a = 14;
    },
    roo: function () {
        alert("baba.a = " + baba.a + "\nthis.a = " + this.a);
    }
};
var theApp = {
    start_action: function () {

        let sola = Object.create(baba);
        sola.foo();
        sola.roo();

        let bola = Object.create(baba);
        bola.roo();            
    }
}
$(document).ready(theApp.start_action);
```

first call to foo after a roo() call we get : 13, 14
second call to foo 13, 13